# Get the index of a datatime in a dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, indexing

`for row in data['column_name']: if row.date() < datetime.today().date(): print(row,????)`

I was not able to get the index of a datatime of a specific column in a dataframe. I used this code and i want to return with the row the index of the row. Could anyone help me please?

Comment: Use `loc`, don't iterate - e.g. `df.loc[df['datetime'].dt.date < pd.Timestamp('now').date()]`. For a detailled answer, please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with something as follows

```
df.index[df['column_name'].dt.date < pd.Timestamp('now').date()].tolist()
```